# What is this in ruby? A hash without curly brackets?

Tags: ruby

I've just seen this in rails RDoc, and I have not seen a hash like that in an array before. I do not know its name. I'd like more doc about it. Would you mind explaining it to me?

```rb
[ model, anchor: model.dom_id ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby allows hash braces to be omitted in a number of places. Most commonly this is seen in method calls:

```
foo(arg, key: value)
# equivalent to (in Ruby 2):
foo(arg, {key: value})
```

The snippet you posted shows an array of two elements with the second one being a hash:

```
[ model, anchor: model.dom_id ]
# equivalent to:
[ model, {anchor: model.dom_id} ]
```

Comment: While the premise of this answer is correct for answering the OP's question, the example given about method signatures is not. Keyword arguments (kwargs) are not the same as a `Hash`. The method signature in your second example `foo(arg,{key: value})` is a syntax error not ruby allowing you to omit `Hash` literal braces.

Comment: In Ruby 3, yes.

Comment: What signature are you referring to? I showed a method call.

Comment: my appologies for some reason I read that as `def foo...` although now you are 100% correct that `Hash` literal and kwargs are separate concepts in 3.0 and not interchangeable like they used to be